# the program is throwing exceptions at me when reading from a file

Tags: java

I have seen this be answered on others and i have tried it but i couldn't find anything that worked for me i was looking for help.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("workspace\Sudoku\file"));
```

it keeps giving me this error `"Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\)"`, the file location is correct by the way. i think it may be because i am using a scanner although i am not 100% sure.

Comment: Try tossing them back.

Comment: That's a compiler error, not an exception. It has nothing to do with using `Scanner`, it's just invalid code.

Comment: You need either to escape the backslash (`workspace\\Sudoku\\file`) or just use `/` - it gets translated to a backslash on Windows.

Comment: It's surprisingly difficult to find a canonical question/answer for this.

Comment: The program is not throwing exceptions at all, let alone at you. Compiler errors are printed. Exceptions are thrown. This is a compiler error. Don't misuse standard terminology.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the escape character which is "\", try this:

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("workspace\\Sudoku\\file"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not escaped properly.

Use:

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File("workspace\\Sudoku\\file"));
```